Replace value of a variable in file using shell
I have below properties file in which I want to replace the value of one of the key using sh commands. Can someone suggest easy way to do same.
Below is the file.
#Sat May 18 20:54:31 SGT 2024
embeddedDatabase=true
maindb.password=abcd12323489843
maindb.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/cim
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
stream.expiration.inactivity.days=28
notification.maximum.rows=100
maindb.user=coverity
maindb.name=cim
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
policymanager.etl.cron.enable=false
elearning.enabled=false
commitPort=9090
cim.ldap.key=ijsihsiohiogsngkosngdnoinoin
dir.temp=/opt/coverity/cov-platform/server/base/temp
policymanager.etl.scheduled.disable=true

I want to replace the value of cim.ldap.key from another file which has another value.
File 2
cim.ldap.key=oidhoighdpoopdfjpoidigdf

Thanks,
Arpit

You can use sed to achieve that:
sed -i -E 's/^cim.ldap.key=.+$/cim.ldap.key=oidhoighdpoopdfjpoidigdf/' file.txt

Assuming that file is called file.txt

Directly by using sed
Assuming file2 do contain only one line you could:
sed -e '/^cim.ldap.key=/{r file2' -e ';d}' -i file1

This will simply do: for all lines that begin by cim.ldap.key= add content of file2, then delete line. (No matter if this file do contain special characters, newlines, slashes or whatever).
You could test by:
sed -e '/^cim.ldap.key=/{r file2' -e ';d}' file1 | diff file1 -

14c14
< cim.ldap.key=ijsihsiohiogsngkosngdnoinoin
---
> cim.ldap.key=oidhoighdpoopdfjpoidigdf

Indirectly by using a shell variable
read var <file2
sed "/^cim.ldap.key=/s/.*/$var/" -i file1

This will do:  for all lines that begin by cim.ldap.key=, replace whole line by content of $var. Note: this syntax is subject to issue, is variable $var do contain a slash /.
Could by written:
read var <file2
sed "/^cim.ldap.key=/s_.*_$var_" -i file1

if $var could contain slashes (/) but no underscore (_). You could replace _ by any character you want while $var don't contain one of them.
